# DB 2 Select Invalid Chracter Found "DECFLOAT"

Tags: sql, select, db2

I get a error in the following SQL Statements:

```
SELECT
    KA.P_NR
    CASE WHEN KA.AS_ROL LIKE 'TEST01%'
        THEN SUBSTRING(KA.AS_ROL, (CHARACTER_LENGTH((KA.AS_ROL)-2), CODEUNITS32), 3, CODEUNITS32)
        ELSE 0
    END IF AS AS_ROL_LD
FROM KA_REST AS KA
```

ERROR:

> AN ERROR while processing the results. - Invalid Character found in a
>   character String of the function "DECFLOAT"

Does anyone know how I can solve this?

Comment: This is not the query your run, this one says _An unexpected token "WHEN" was found following "KA.P_NR CASE".  Expected tokens may include:  ","_

Comment: yes it it is not exact. I cant post it, because company safety. But the error is on (KA.AS_ROL)-2

Comment: Probably what you intended was CHARACTER_LENGTH(KA.AS_ROL)-2

Comment: Please specify the exact column datatype for KA.AS_ROL and its length.  You seem to be saying that CHARACTER_LENGTH() throws an exception but LENGTH() does not throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
THEN SUBSTRING(KA.AS_ROL, (CHARACTER_LENGTH((KA.AS_ROL)-2), CODEUNITS32), 3, CODEUNITS32)
```

Can be expressed with

```
THEN RIGHT(KA.AS_ROL, 3, CODEUNITS32)
```

Comment: I solved the problem with 

THEN SUBSTRING(KA.AS_ROL, (LENGTH(KA.AS_ROL)-2), 3, CODEUNITS32)  

I get the same result before with chaning to UTF8. We change our db2 from ascii to UTF8. You think we can get a problem in the future with this sql statement?

Comment: @Michael2704 No, but if AS_ROL is CHAR or VARCHAR not defined FOR BIT DATA, then CODEUNITS32 is used by default and it's optional. I'd use RIGHT(KA.AS_ROL, 3) just for readability